# Check if const array is sorted during compile time (C language)

Tags: c, compilation

In C language, how to check during compile time if a const array is sorted (in ascending order) or not.

Given an array like this:
const int a[] = {4,5,6,8};

Compilation should fail with error if the above array is not sorted.

Is that even possible?

Comment: You can't check it with a C compiler. You need to use a separate tool.

Comment: Conditional Preprocessor can help

Comment: @Dayalrai : Can you please elaborate. Or help write a code for that.

Comment: you could define MACRO which will check if array is sorted or not. in case of failure use `#if ..#error ..#endif` block

Comment: One nice and fun way to make sure stuff is right is to generate such stuff. E.g. using f#: ``let sb = new System.StringBuilder() in sb.Write("static const int a["); let a = [4..8] in sb.Write(a.Length.ToString()); sb.WriteLine("] = {"); a |> List.iter (fun v -> sb.Write(sprintf "%d, " v)); sb.WriteLine("};"); System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\temp\myarray.txt", sb.ToString())``

Comment: @BitTickler can't see `c` in your example.

Comment: And for a good reason: GENERATE C code does not require C ;)

Comment: @Dayalrai : In MACRO, how do we loop through the array. I understand the use of #if and #error. But, actual C code will help. Thanks.

Comment: @neo due to comment limitation, i have pasted a demo code in answer.

Comment: I don't see how this could be solved *generically* using macros, even using [variadic macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro).

Comment: Thanks @Dayalrai but as Joachim mentioned, this does not solve the problem generically. You have assumed that element size is 3.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i agree. my answer was an effort to show possible solution. thanks for comments. i will remove my answer

Comment: Since a 'smart' person is writing the source code, we could reasonably assume the coder would write the constant arrays correctly,  After all that 'smart' person would also be the one writing the pre-processor macros to check the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is *very* difficult to do generically at compilation time, it may even be impossible with the standard tools (preprocessor, etc).

Perhaps a better solution would be to, as soon as possible after array creation, simply have code check it (which you can also disable like `assert`):

```
const int a[] = { 4, 5, 6, 8 };
#ifndef NDEBUG
for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
    if (a[i-1] > a[i]) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s(%d) Check your arrays\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        exit(1);
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.

Although some have suggested that the preprocessor can help, it cannot be a complete solution because the preprocessor is a limited scripting language that operates on the text in the file, it cannot operate on the values from the result of compiling, and the preprocessor does not have access to loops or recursion in a general sense like with higher level languages.

But that will not stop us from detecting if an array is sorted at *compile time* and we can achieve this by using the compilers optimizer to compute whether the list is sorted and place that value into the .rodata section of the compiled binary. Then we can parse the compiled object file, mine it for data that indicates the determination, and know whether the list is sorted before linking the final binary. Yes, this is tricky, but it *can* be done!

For this answer, I make a few assumptions:

0. You desire a single point of control in the code for changing the contents of the array
1. You're using *make* for your build process, and you can modify your Makefiles
2. You have access to the standard suite of linux command line tools
3. You're using *C++* (more on this later)

Here's the proof-of-concept:

main.cpp:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
// isListSorted is evaluated at compile time to populate a const int
constexpr uint8_t isListSorted(const int * list, size_t sizeOfList)
{
    uint8_t retVal = 1;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < sizeOfList; i++) retVal &= list[i-1] <= list[i];
    return retVal;
}
// numList needs to be sorted to pass compilation, last two values are out of order and 
// will not compile
const int numList [] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 4};
const uint8_t isSorted = isListSorted(numList, sizeof(numList)/sizeof(const int));
int main()
{    
    return 0; 
}
```

Makefile:

```
CXX?=g++
EXE:=sorted-const-array
SOURCES:=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))
.PHONY: all
all: $(EXE)
# Target for all cpp files
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $^ -o $@
# This dependency chain means that if main.cpp changes, then the sort check is recomputed 
# This target picks out the .rodata section of the object file
main.rodata: main.o
    objcopy -j.rodata -O binary $< $@ 
# This target picks out the is sorted determination in the .rodata section
main.bin: main.rodata 
    dd if=$< of=$@ bs=1 skip=`readelf -Ws main.o | grep -m 1 isSorted\
     | awk '{split($$0,a," ");print a[2]}' | xargs echo "ibase=16;" | bc` count=1
# This Phony Target produces no files, but returns 0 to make when the scan of
# main.o indicates arrays are not sorted in the else case. The is the mechanism that 
# guards against compiling unordered arrays
.PHONY: checkNumListSorted
checkNumListSorted: main.bin
    @if [ `xxd $< | awk '{split($$0,a," ");print a[2]}'` = "01" ]; then\
        echo "Arrays sorted";\
    else\
        echo "Arrays NOT sorted"; false;\
    fi
# Make the top level target dependent on a phony target that succeeds if and  
# only if numList is sorted. 
$(EXE): checkNumListSorted $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) $(LIB) -o $@
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(EXE) *.o *.rodata *.bin
```

Running produces:

```
$ make 
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
objcopy -j.rodata -O binary main.o main.rodata 
dd if=main.rodata of=main.bin bs=1 skip=`readelf -Ws main.o | grep -m 1 isSorted\
 | awk '{split($0,a," ");print a[2]}' | xargs echo "ibase=16;" | bc` count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0.000301472 s, 3.3 kB/s
Arrays NOT sorted
make: *** [Makefile:24: checkNumListSorted] Error 1
```

Fixing the order and rerunning the build process produces

```
$ make 
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
objcopy -j.rodata -O binary main.o main.rodata 
dd if=main.rodata of=main.bin bs=1 skip=`readelf -Ws main.o | grep -m 1 isSorted\
 | awk '{split($0,a," ");print a[2]}' | xargs echo "ibase=16;" | bc` count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1 byte copied, 0.000102414 s, 9.8 kB/s
Arrays sorted
g++  main.o  -o sorted-const-array
```

The reason I used C++ is that I exploited constexpr as a hint to the compiler that the function that computes whether we're sorted can be computed. This gives us access to loops that can operate on arbitrarily sized data and allows us to compute this at compile time. But it's cheating in the sense that you asked specifically for a *C* implementation of this. Although constexpr has existed in the C++ standard for over a decade, as of C23, [it is now a part of C standard as well](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constexpr). You could use this approach for C, if you're using the absolute newest compilers at the start of 2024.

For passersby, why would you want to do something like this? For larger projects, involving multiple developers, over a long period of time, you need automated means to check assumptions your code relies on. This protects you from strange, difficult to reproduce bugs. Doing this at *compile time* ensures that you're not offloading this checking onto your users. A build that fails, because an assumption is broken, is a great automated check.

Comment: Hmm, this solution seems dubious. OP question was tagged [tag:c], and there is plenty of good C code that cannot be compiled as C++. Further, C23 `constexpr` differs from C++ `constexpr`; in particular, C23 only allows objects to be `constexpr`, not functions.